# How to transfer params to GET method in Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following URL:

```
'http://localhost/track/' + id + '/fromdate/' + date_start + '/todate/' + date_end
```

And there is handler in Node.js part:

```
app.get('/track/:id/fromdate/:fromdate/todate/:todate', function(req, res){
  alert(req.params.fromdate);
});
```

Why I can not get `req.params.fromdate`

Comment: node.js has no alert function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this please:

```
'http://localhost/track/' + encodeURIComponent(id) + '/fromdate/' + encodeURIComponent(date_start)+ '/todate/' + encodeURIComponent(date_end)
```

when you are making a get request, you should turn the parameters into encoded URI components like in the example i give